# How can i image upload on another Ruby on Rails application using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, spree

I have Two Application.

1. Spree Application
2. Rails Application

I have configure 1 module.

That module have image upload functionality.

I have to upload image in another application which is Rails Application.

How can i configure two application each other ?

How can i upload image on another Rails application and get URL back to Spree Application and that URL store in Spree Application ?

Comment: Are these applications hosted on the same server?

Comment: @davidb, right now i am working localy. After completed then i will deploy.
It may be on Same server.

Comment: Can you please post the Paperclip specific content of the module your tablking about and also the module in the second application where you want the image too.

Comment: @davidb, First Application i want to just app data with image but only image store in Second Application not in First Application, But First Application have one table with field Name,ImagUrl . 
In ImageUrl is a string and it store ImageUrl which is stored in Second Application.
My purpose is that not load on single application for Image.
Also Mobile Developer use that application via API.

Comment: @davidb, I give one example.

For example I user AWS for storing image using paper clip. But i want to image upload on Rails Application instead of AWS. It is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Answer.

This Answer for Two Application Hosted in Same Server.

First Application Which is in Spree. It have Image Model with attachment Field.

**Change Code in "path" and "url" to upload image on another rails application which is hosted in same server.**

For Example :

has_attached_file :attachment,

```
      styles: { mini: '48x48>', small: '100x100>', product: '240x240>', large: '600x600>' },

      default_style: :product,

           url: "#{MEDIASERVER_URL}/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",

           path: "#{MEDIASERVER_PATH}/public/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",

          convert_options: { all: '-strip -auto-orient -colorspace sRGB' }
```

**MEDIASERVER_URL** is a url to getting image from remotely. **for example http://localhost:4000**

**MEDIASERVER_PATH** is a path to store image in which location. It is a another rails application . **for example /home/ServerName/ProjectName**
    enter code here